# HTML + Ionic 3.x: How to use a for loop in the html file using in instead of of

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, ionic2, ionic3

I have several arrays of objects in my typescript file.

I want to iterate through these arrays simultaneously and display their contents in the html file. Here is the content:

```
<ion-item>
  {{array1[i]}} {{array2[i]}} {{array3[i]}}
</ion-item>
```

Luckily the arrays are always the same size. Now I want to do a for-loop after the ion-item (something like this):

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let i in array1">
  {{array1[i]}} {{array2[i]}} {{array3[i]}}
</ion-item>
```

But doing it this way gives me an error: "Can't bind 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'. Now I've found the following workaround, but it seems pretty ugly.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let counter of array1; let i = index">
  {{array1[i]}} {{array2[i]}} {{array3[i]}}
</ion-item>
```

Any advice on how to do this more efficiently / pretty would be highly appreciated :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You last is the best yet, but here is an other way

TS

```
for(let i=0; i < n; i++){ // n is array.length
   this.globalArray.push({ a1 : array1[i] , a2 : array2[i] , a3 : array3[i] });
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of globalArray;">
  {{item.a1}} {{item.a1}} {{item.a1}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Well, that's an example of a foreach loop, not a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple

```
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of array1">{{item.property}}<li>
    <ul>
   <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of array2">{{item.property}}<li>
    <ul>
   <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of array3">{{item.property}}<li>
   <ul>
```