# Ionic 3 how to use for loop in typescript?

Tags: typescript, for-loop, ionic-framework

We can use `ngFor` in `HTML` like

```
*ngFor="let file of files"
```

but I want to apply **For loop** in typescript. How can i use **For loop**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML + Ionic 3.x: How to use a for loop in the html file using in instead of of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894387/html-ionic-3-x-how-to-use-a-for-loop-in-the-html-file-using-in-instead-of-of)

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply like:

```
for(let file of this.filename) {
   console.log(file);
}
```

or like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.filename.length; i++) {
   console.log(this.filename[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer this code,

```
for (let file of this.files){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can use forEach:

```
files.forEach((res) => {
   //your each object will be in res
   //example: let value = res
});
```